# Running Multiple Test Cases in same Window one by one

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

I am using Selenium Web Driver with Java for my Testing,  I have a Problem with Running multiple Test Cases in Same Browser Window One By One. Can anyone help me??

**Thank you!!**

Comment: Provide your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can help you if you don't allow them to :)
So,please elaborate your question or provide some code so that people can analyse and help.

> have a Problem with Running multiple Test Cases

Use loop to execute testcases one by one ;)

Comment: Thank you.      but I just want to Run my Test Cases on a Browser which is already Open. I Don't want to Open new Browser Window

Answer (score 0):

With my best guess. you are running multiple instances without completing one. Start different thread for each execution and at the end close each browser.

Comment: Thank you. but I just want to Run my Test Cases on a Browser which is already Open. I Don't want to Open new Browser Window